# Android - set listview height

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a listview that's in a tablerow.  The data is showing up but I want the listview to be "taller" (more height), but I can't seem to figure out how.  I've set the height in the xml to everything (300dp, 500dp, wrap_content) but nothing seems to be effecting it.  Here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="#98c4ed">
 <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:shrinkColumns="1"
      android:layout_margin="5dp">
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/trSubStatus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSubStatusLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sub-Status:"
                style="@style/IssueDetailsLabelTextView" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSubStatus"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/IssueDetailsTextView" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/trDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDescriptionLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Description:"
                style="@style/IssueDetailsLabelTextView" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/IssueDetailsTextView" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/trActivities"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvActivitiesLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Issue Activities:"
                style="@style/IssueDetailsLabelTextView" />
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lvActivities"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">
            </ListView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/trLast"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

right now, the listview is being populated but it's height varies and I have to scroll within the listview to see more.  EDIT: Sorry, meant to put that it's the lvActivities in the trActivities row that I'm having issues with.

Edit:
What I would like is the ListView to be xx amount in height.  The listview is the last control on the layout, so if the data that's put in the controls above it, make the layout exceed the page, I'd like for the page to scroll to see the lvActivities.  Right now, the LlvActivities is shrinking or expanding to the page size and it's a pain to scroll through the lvActivities when it's only 1/2 inch tall (beacuse of the data in the other controls).

Comment: Try `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to listView as well.

Comment: I tried this and it makes the row extremly small...

Comment: Ok. Then try `android:weightSum` to the row and `android:weight` to the listview. Like if your weightsum is like 7, then put weight = 5 to listview. Also make sure at least your row height is big enough. If not, then apply the `android:weightSum` to its parent too.

Comment: Same as my comment below....it expands it, but only until the bottom of the screen, then it cuts it off (making the listview scrollable).  I'd like the whole screen to scroll and not the listview.  Won't a linearlayout auto scroll if the contents are larger than the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `android:minHeight` , `android:minWidth` , `android:maxHeight` , `android:maxWidth`??

Comment: I used minHeight:500dp and it only made it a little bigger.  even when I use 5000dp, there is no change from 500dp.  Also, I don't have a maxHeight or maxWidth property.  Using ASUS EEE Tablet on Ice Cream 4.0.3

Comment: If you try to change the `android:layout_height="500dp"` defined in the TableRow parent of the ListView for a wrap_content? or this is not what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Try this-->

```
list.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, theSizeIWant));

;
```